# how to click in this element by python selenuim

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

how can i click in this element i have alot of element that have role = button and class name and touchable

```
<a role="button" class="_56bz _54k8 _5c9u _5caa" data-store="{&quot;log_data&quot;:{&quot;page_id&quot;:10965642141242,&quot;source&quot;:null,&quot;referrer&quot;:null,&quot;platform&quot;:&quot;mtouch&quot;},&quot;event_name&quot;:&quot;tapped_more_button&quot;,&quot;module_name&quot;:&quot;pages_public_view&quot;}" aria-label="" data-sigil="touchable"><i class="_5c9v _56br _4q9b img sp_l-Rkd1MGdk7 sx_0acc7f"></i><span class="_55sr">المزيد</span></a>
```

Comment: How about this text `المزيد` ?

Comment: Check if //a[./span[.='المزيد']] works in the developer console.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

inside chrome dev tools you can select the element and choose 'copy as xpath' and it will give a unique selector.

Comment: i had this xpath how to write it 

`//*[@id="action_bar"]/div[4]/a`

Comment: `driver.find_element_by_xpath()`

Comment: i mean how to write it in the ()

Comment: `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="action_bar"]/div[4]/a')`

Comment: i tried to copy this element by xpath but didnt work why ?

his xpath is `//*[@id="u_0_j_Ac"]`
and all element is 

`<div class="_59k _2rgt _1j-f _2rgt" style="font-size: 17px;font-weight: 500;line-height: 20px;text-align: right;color: #050505" id="u_0_j_Ac" aria-label="عام" role="button" tabindex="0" data-nt="FB:TEXT4">عام</div>`

Comment: can you show the code you wrote?

Comment: driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="u_0_j_Ac"]').click()

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="u_0_a_SS"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=96.0.4664.93)

Comment: i think the ids are dynamically generated.  
can you verify if the ids stay consistent if you refresh the page?  
- locate some element, copy the selector  
- refresh  
- locate the element, copy the selector again  
- verify that both selectors match

Comment: yes its dynamically generated how to fix it

Comment: you can query using the element text as others comments have suggested.

Comment: check @Arundeep comment.

Comment: //a[./span[.='المزيد']] dynamically not stable